# Finding Android Java usable methods in a Shared Object File

Tags: java, android, shared-objects

I need to see which methods are available in a .so file so i can use them like `private native int JNIMethod(String args);` in Java.
Is this possible? if yes, How?

 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nm, objdump or readelf` to see the exposed functions in a .so file. Example:

```
objdump -T your_shared_object.so | c++filt
```

Piping the result to `c++filt` is only necessary if the names are mangled.